# Cannot Serialize Neurotec NTemplate using c# - protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a Neurotec NTemplate with one Finger record. Now i want to Serialize it with c# - protobuf-net. I dont getting any exeption but my MemoryStream is emplty. 
what might be the problem?

code Is below:(where tenPrintTemplate is a NTemplate)

```
 tenPrintTemplate.AddFingers(fingerPrintTemplate.Save());
     //start Proto Buffer serialization  
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true;  
 RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(NTemplate), false);    
 ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<NTemplate>(stream, tenPrintTemplate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution of serializing Neurotec's NTemplate using C# Protobuf-net. i'm adding the solution code below. if anyone face the same problem please use it as your solution.

```
//Its a NTemplate of TenPrint
tenPrintTemplate.AddFingers(fingerPrintTemplate.Save());
//start Proto Buffer serialization
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

int tenpritnTemplateSize = tenPrintTemplate.GetSize();
NBuffer buffer = new NBuffer(tenpritnTemplateSize);
// saving fingers template to buffer.
tenPrintTemplate.Save(buffer);
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<byte[]>(stream, buffer.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you've told it not to apply any standard pattern / configuration logic:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(NTemplate), false);
```

so you have basically told it "serialize nothing". If you specify `false`, it expects *you* to tell it how you want it to work, for example by using `Add` on the `MetaType` that is returned. I suspect you could also just specify `true` if it has suitable attributes.

Note that 0 is a perfectly reasonable length for protobuf-net and an object that doesn't have anything interesting to mention on the wire.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for you reply. after your suggestion it set RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(NTemplate), true); but nothing changed. i see the capacity and length properties of MemoryStream, both is 0.